# Integer solutions of $x^3 = 7y^3 + 6 y^2+2 y$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves

Does the equation  $$x^3 = 7y^3 + 6 y^2+2 y\tag{1}$$ have any positive integer solutions?  This is equivalent to a conjecture about [OEIS sequence A245624](https://oeis.org/A245624).

Maple tells me this is a curve of genus $1$, and its Weierstrass form is $s^3 + t^2 + 20 = 0$, with $$ \eqalign{ s = \dfrac{-2(7 y^2 + 6 y + 2)}{x^2},& \
t = \dfrac{-2(3 x^3 + 14 y^2 + 12 y + 4)}{x^3}\cr
x = \dfrac{-2s(t-6)}{s^3+56},&\ y = \dfrac{4t-24}{s^3+56}}$$
So I can find rational points on both curves, but I haven't been able to find integer points on (1) other than the trivial $(0,0)$.

Comment: I guess you should look at this once : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation

Comment: I dread number-theoretical questions which not even Robert Israel can answer... :-|

Comment: No solutions for $y\le10^7$.

Comment: $\gcd(y, 7y^2 + 6 y + 2)$ is either $1$ or $2.$ Either $y=n^3$ or $y = 4 n^3,$ and then $7y^2 + 6 y + 2...$

Comment: Robert, comes down to a Mordell curve, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1288687/integral-solutions-to-56u2-12-u-1-w3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ \gcd(y, 7y^2 + 6 y + 2) = 1,2  $$

The first case is odd $y,$ so that $7y^2 + 6y+2$ is odd and $\gcd(y, 7y^2 + 6 y + 2) = 1.$ Both $y$ and $7y^2 + 6 y + 2$ must be cubes. Take $y = n^3.$ We want $7n^6 + 6 n^3 + 2$ to be a cube. Cubes are $1,0,-1 \pmod 9.$ If $n \equiv 0 \pmod 3,$ then $7n^6 + 6 n^3 + 2 \equiv 2 \pmod 9$ and is not a cube. If $n^3 \equiv 1 \pmod 9,$ then $7n^6 + 6 n^3 + 2 \equiv 6 \pmod 9$ and is not a cube. If $n^3 \equiv -1 \pmod 9,$ then $7n^6 + 6 n^3 + 2 \equiv 3 \pmod 9$ and is not a cube.

Next
$\gcd(y, 7y^2 + 6 y + 2) = 2.$ Both $y= 4n^3$ and $7y^2 + 6 y + 2 = 2 w^3$ .
give me a minute, it is not guaranteed to be easy just because the other case was. Hmmm, it is possible both mod 9 and mod 7, which reflects the solution with my $n=0, w=0.$ Sigh. Just taking $y=4u,$ there may be a tractable way to deal with $56u^2 + 12 u + 1 = w^3.$

Monday: computer suggests the only integer point on $56u^2 + 12 u + 1 = w^3$ is $(0,1),$ which would finish the problem if confirmed. CONFIRMED: see [Integral solutions to $56u^2 + 12 u + 1 = w^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1288687/integral-solutions-to-56u2-12-u-1-w3)

Comment: The curve $56u^2+12u+1=w^3$ is basically in Weierstrass form (modulo a scalar change of variables; say $E$ is the model in Weierstrass form), so it suffices to find all the S-integral points on $E$ (I believe S here is {7}, i.e., we need points with a denominator which is at worst a power of 7). This *can* be done. The rank of $E$ is 2, trivial torsion.

Comment: @ÁlvaroLozano-Robledo, thank you; I suspected it would be more approachable than various other things that came up. If you know how to finish the argument, please do so. I lack such techniques. Meanwhile, I believe the argument about the gcd is correct, but there has been no comment on that.

Comment: @ÁlvaroLozano-Robledo, aahh, Keith Conrad is there. I've met him once or twice, friends in common.

Comment: The technique needed here is that of linear forms in complex and p-adic elliptic logarithms... something I am not an expert on. Magma, however, has these implemented and can calculate S-integral points.

Comment: @ÁlvaroLozano-Robledo, thanks. Magma does have an online demonstration window that will do a single calculation, no matter how many lines it takes to describe it. I use that for finding the genus of positive ternary quadratic forms that contain any single given form.   http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc

Comment: @ÁlvaroLozano-Robledo, see Mordell curve at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1288687/integral-solutions-to-56u2-12-u-1-w3

Comment: Nice! I'm glad to see that taken care of.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, I took a generator $P$ of the Mordell-Weil group of $y^2=x^3-20$ and computed the preimage of $k\cdot P$ for $|k| \leq 300$ back to the original curve, and the only instance where the point was integral was for $k=0$.

Comment: Actually, make that |k|<1000.

Comment: Can you translate that into bounds for the original curve?

Comment: What do you mean by bounds? On the height of the points? If we knew how to bound the height of the points on the original curve in terms of the heights of the points on the Weierstrass form, then we would be done... but I don't know how to do this.